# Customizing and Translating Text in Firebase UI Auth SignInScreen for French Language

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm working on an app using the firebase_ui_auth package for authentication, and I need to customize and translate the text displayed on the SignInScreen to French. Specifically, I want to provide a localized experience for my French-speaking users.

I've already integrated the firebase_ui_auth package, and the SignInScreen is working as expected. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with customizing and translating the text.

Can someone please guide me on how to achieve the following:

1. Customize the text displayed on the SignInScreen (e.g., changing "Sign in with Google" to "Se connecter avec Google").
2. Ensure that the text is translated into French for a localized experience.

Any code snippets or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From looking at the [example on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ui_auth/example), it looks like FirebaseUI picks up the locale that you specify with:

```
locale: const Locale('en')
```

To learn more about the package, I recommend checking out its [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/tree/main/packages/firebase_ui_auth), specifically its [getting started](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/tree/main/packages/firebase_ui_auth) guide and the guide on [localization](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Flutter/blob/main/packages/firebase_ui_localizations/README.md).